# MVC 3 I can't add a new controller or view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I have installed the MVC 3, but after I've created that project, if I want to add a new Controller or View but there is no item in the list. See the images below. What's wrong ?

The project's targer framework is of course .NET 4

I have that items installed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the option to start a new MVC project?

Comment: Yes, if I choose the .NET Framework 4 when creating a new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

the purpose was, when I've opened the `.csproj` file there were wrong `ProjectTypeGuids`. I've replaced them with the data from the empty project and now it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to add MVC components to an ASP.NET Web project, rather than an ASP.NET MVC Web Project

Comment: but the whole project is the MVC project, not the ASP.NET project